# force directed nodes with circle packing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, circle-pack

I want to create a Circle Packing for each node on a force directed layout. I am searching for an example, but I can't find any. I am new to D3 and infovis. I have tried a few layouts, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by circle packing? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: @PratikPatel I think s/he means d3's pack layout https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout

Comment: I mean something like the balloon tree layout: http://bl.ocks.org/justinvdm/3676778. The only problem with this is that he has forked from d3 v2 and i am unable to understand the layout, it is nothing like the usual d3 examples. I need such a layout because i need hierarchical data as well as associative data representation together. Currently i am working on adding association to the pack layout.

Comment: Hey did u find the solution for this? If yes, then please help